# What does it mean by "the origin is moved by the transformation" in linear transformations?

Tags: matrices, transformation

Linear transformations have the special property that the origin is not moved by the transformation.

I don't really understand what this means.

The example I'm given is that the following transformation is not linear because if this:

From (x, y) with a transformation of (x+4, y-1).

Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: Do you mean from $(x, y)$ rather than $(2, 3)$?

Comment: For linear map $T(\alpha x) = \alpha T(x)$. Hence $T(0) = 0$ (ie. the origin is not moved)

Comment: Yes I mean (x, y)

Answer (score 2):

In two dimensional space, $(0,0)$ represents the origin. So in two dimensional space, the statement that "If a transformation is linear, then the origin is not moved by that transformation" can be written as follows.

- If $T$ is linear, then $T(0,0) = (0,0)$.

Equivalently, (see also, [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)) we have that:

- If $T(0,0) \neq (0,0),$ then $T$ is not linear.

So for instance, letting $T(x,y) = (x+4,y-1),$ we can compute $$T(0,0) = (0+4,0-1) = (4,-1) \neq (0,0).$$

Thus $T$ is not linear.

Comment: adding on: transformations that *do* 'move the origin' are known as [affine maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)